# ASP.net Gridview Auto Scroll to bottom on refresh, if scroll bar position is at bottom before refresh

Tags: asp.net, gridview, scroll

I have a ASP.net gridview that reads from a txt file. On refresh it maintains scrollbar position.

**Current Maintain Scroll Pos code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_pageLoaded(pageLoaded);


function pageLoaded(sender, args) {

    Func()

}
function Func() {//document.getElementById("hdnScrollTop").value
    document.getElementById("divScroll").scrollTop = document.getElementById("hdnScrollTop").value;
}
function Func2() {
    var s = document.getElementById("divScroll").scrollTop;

    document.getElementById('hdnScrollTop').value = s;

}
```

**PROBLEM:**
When scroll position is at the current bottom I want it to go to the new bottom on a refresh. How can I get it to do that?

**Additional Code**

[ScrollWAjax.aspx [pastebin]](http://pastebin.com/PGVHswiS)

[ScrollWAjax.aspx.cs [pastebin]](http://pastebin.com/pDtyseAA)

**Other Possible Solutions**

- check scroll bar position (how?), if at bottom then scrolltop = 500 (sends to bottom)
- Check if scrollbar is clicked(how?), if clicked don't refresh. Otherwise scrolltop = 500

Comment: By 'refresh', do you mean a button or some control triggers it or page refresh by F5?

Comment: I mean Timer within an Update Panel, and a DataBind(). I added the code in a pastebin link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized a simple solution. The divider has an onmousedown and onmouseup attributes and I used these functions on mousedown and up to stop the timer and start the timer. This fixed the problem now when someone clicks the scrollbar it stops the timer and doesn't refresh. When they let go it resumes the timer which on tick is set to go to the bottom of the page :-)

```
function startTimer() {
    var timer = $find("<%=Timer1.ClientID%>")
    timer._startTimer();
    Func();
}

function stopTimer() {
    var timer = $find("<%=Timer1.ClientID%>")
    timer._stopTimer();
}
```

Comment: it does not maintain its position on refresh, but it does allow the user all the time they need to view the information using the scrollbar

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken you are doing an ajax call. Thus you are able to subscribe to the endrequest where you can set the new scroll position.

```
prm.add_endRequest(endRequestHandler);
prm.add_beginRequest(beginRequestHandler);

var scrolledToBottom = false;

function beginRequestHandler(sender, args){
    if($("#pnlGrid").scrollTop() + $("#pnlGrid").innerHeight() >= $("#pnlGrid").prop("scrollHeight")) {
        scrolledToBottom  = true;
    }
}

function endRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    if(scrolledToBottom){
        $("#pnlGrid").scrollTop($("#pnlGrid").prop("scrollHeight"));
    }
}
```

Comment: right but how do I set the scroll position to the bottom? like this?
$get('pnlgrid').scrollLeft = xPos;  and xPos is what I calculate to be the bottom? is it by lines?

Comment: @user3669835 I updated the answer. Is it what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it. This code assumes that you have a panel `pnlgrid` around your gridview. This requires reference to jquery file.

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
  if (!Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().get_isInAsyncPostBack()) {
    var xPos, yPos;
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
  }
}

function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
     xPos = $get('pnlgrid').scrollLeft;
     yPos = $get('pnlgrid').scrollTop;
}

function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    $get('pnlgrid').scrollLeft = xPos;
    $get('pnlgrid').scrollTop = yPos;
}
```

Let me know if this not what you are looking for but provide more info I would be glad to help.

Comment: Seems to be exactly what I'm looking for, by panel you mean update panel right? or do you mean the div that has the scroll?

Comment: I've tried it, it doesn't seem to work. Maybe I'm referencing the jquery file wrong can you explain briefly how that is done? I'm new to jquery. It seems it is just maining its position in the data. So when a new line is added and the gridview is refreshed it just stays at the current position.

Comment: I guess here is a better question, How can I check to see if the scroll position is at the bottom? Then I can set scrollTop to any large int value and it will go straight to the bottom.(tried that) I just can't figure out how to check if the scrollbar is at the bottom.

Comment: I meant the div that has the scroll or `asp:Panel` and not the updatepanel. I understand what you're trying to achieve but give me an hour or so I'll have a look when I am back in office.